# Is there any way to set an RSpec expectation to receive a method call as an argument?

Tags: ruby, rspec, boolean-expression

Ie

> expect(my_class).to receive(:method_b).with(:calling_method_b_here)

(it's not the return value I want, but specifically to test that method_b is called in this way)

?

Comment: No. I am not aware of. But you can show us your code, so that we can suggest you there, to change the method you wrote by suggesting some changes and make your unit test easy.

Comment: @ArupRakshit don't know if it matters to you but this is very possible. See my answer below for testing such a thing.

Comment: @engin this doesn't make sense to test method call in argument list.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you if I understand correctly:

```
it "should call #method_b when I call #method_that_calls_b" do 
  expect(my_class).to receive(:method_b).with(anything) #anything means I don't care explictly what is sent in just that it was called
  my_class.method_that_calls_b
end
```

This will test that `method_that_calls_b` actually does call `method_b` with any arguments. If you know what arguments it is supposed to receive then replace anything with what you expect it to be called with. e.g.

```
it "should call #method_b with 'hello'" do 
   expect(my_class).to receive(:method_b).with('hello')
   my_class.method_b('goodbye') #this will fail
   my_class.method_b('hello') #this will pass without the above line
end
```

Comment: Writing test code controversial :-) I am not Kent Beck... Hehehe.. But I wouldn't write the test the way OP asked... That's why I asked him to show the code.

Comment: +1 although I think `.with(anything)` is pointless, I would just leave it off.

Comment: @p11y I agree but he specifically ask for the `with` method so i wanted to show it.

Comment: @ArupRakshit I can understand why you did not answer but the question was asked in a vague manner and received a vague response appropriately.